# circuit macros latex, error noCurrentPoint

Tags: pstricks

Following the [manual](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/graphics/circuit_macros/doc/CMman.pdf) of Circuit macros for LaTeX, just at the beginning I try to make the first circuit picture in LaTeX "quick.m4" processing that first with m4, then dpic, and adding the code exactly like in the manual to a new LaTeX document. I have tried a lot of time but I have always the same error about the line

```
\psset{noCurrentPoint}
```

What does it mean?

P.S. I run pdflatex on linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 36 of the manual:

> 15.PSTricks anomaly: If you are using PSTricks and you get the error message Graphics parameter ‘noCurrentPoint’ not defined.. then your
>   version of PSTricks is older than August 2010. You can do the
>   following ...

Comment: thanks. The version of PStricks was of 2009, because Ubuntu still use this obsolete version of latex... I am updating all the packages

Answer (score 0):

`\spline` is a basic `eepic` drawing command rather than a `pstricks` macro so it looks like you have invoked `dpic` without the `-p` (or other) option. Look at the Quick Start section of the Circuit_macros manual to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The important file is `quick.tex`; make sure that it contains valid PSTricks code; that is, it should start with the two lines

```
\psset{unit=1in,cornersize=absolute,dimen=middle}%
\begin{pspicture}
...
```

If it does not then `m4` and `dpic -p` have not been called correctly.  If it does then it sounds as if you are not using a postscript viewer that displays graphics.  The command sequence should be

```
latex q
dvips q
```

which produces the postscript file `q.ps`.  Print it or look at it with `gsview`.

Comment: @Jerry: Note that you can edit your answers in case if you want to add further information. If this is however intended as a separate alternative solution than it is ok to post it separatly.